# How to store path found from Iterative deepening depth-first search

Tags: graph, depth-first-search, path-finding, iterative-deepening

I am trying to use an array to store the path found from [Iterative deepening depth-first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterative_deepening_depth-first_search)  algorithm.

> I have N vertexs and I want to store the path from vertex X to vertex
>   Y by the array pathTo[N] with 
>   pathTo[W] = V means node W will be visited from node V i.e V is the parent of W in dfs tree. (So by tracing parents back from N, we can find the path that leads to N.)

Can anyone help me to implement it in pseudo code ? I will try to learn from it. 
I have tried reading other posts about this problem but I still can't understand at all.